# [XmlHttpRequest][react-native] xhr.upload.onprogress not working with xhr.send({uri: 'file:///...'})

Tags: android, react-native, youtube, xmlhttprequest, form-data

I'm trying to upload video with youtube v3 API, looking on [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) example.

So, I wrote something like this:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('PUT', this.url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', this.contentType); <=== video/mp4
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Range', 'bytes ' + this.offset + '-' + (end - 1) + '/' + this.filesize);
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Upload-Content-Type', this.filetype);  <=== video/mp4

if (xhr.upload) {
  xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', this.onProgress);
}
xhr.onload = this.onContentUploadSuccess_.bind(this);
xhr.onerror = this.onContentUploadError_.bind(this);
xhr.send({uri: this.file.path});  <=== file:///.....
```

and it works, i have `xhr.onload` and `xhr.onerror` and video file is uploaded to youtube and played there.

But i haven't `xhr.upload.onprogress`.

I try `xhr.onprogress`, `xhr.upload.onprogress`, `xhr.upload.addEventListener` - all of this not works.

BUT!
When i use `FormData`

```js
let data = new FormData();
data.append('File', {
      uri:  source.path,
      type: source.type,
      name: source.name
});
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('PUT', this.url, true);
  //xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', this.contentType);  
  //=== comment this, because it throw error 'multipart != video/mp4'
  //xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Range', 'bytes ' + this.offset + '-' + (end - 1) + '/' + this.filesize);
  //=== comment this, because sending data size != filesize
  xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Upload-Content-Type', this.filetype);

  if (xhr.upload) {
    xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', this.onProgress);
  }
  xhr.onload = this.onContentUploadSuccess_.bind(this);
  xhr.onerror = this.onContentUploadError_.bind(this);
  xhr.send(data); <==== FormData
```

`xhr.upload.onprogress` is working. But then youtube api return processing error, because it support only 'video/*' and 'application/octet-stream' and does not support 'multipart/form-data'.

What I do wrong and what I need to do for using `xhr.upload.onprogress` WITHOUT `FormData`?

P.S. sorry for my ugly english

- react-native v0.47.2
- node v8.2.1
- npm v5.3.0
- Target Platform: Android
- Development Operating System: MacOS
- Build tools: Android SDK

Answer (score 0):

This post was a while ago, but try this:

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('PUT', uploadUrl);
xhr.onLoad = this.onContentUploadSuccess_.bind(this);
xhr.onerror = this.onContentUploadError_.bind(this);
...formData here
xhr.send(formData);
if (xhr.upload) {
  xhr.upload.onprogress = ({ total, loaded }) => console.log(loaded / total);
}
```

Placing xhr.upload.onprogress at the end did it for me. Check the [Firefox docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/upload) to get the event details (as in loaded, total). Make sure to deconstruct total and loaded the way I did above.